# how many permutations of {1,2,...,9}

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many permutations of {1,2,…,9} are there such that 1 does not immediately precede 2, 2 does not immediately precede 3, and so forth up to 8 not immediately preceding 9? One obvious example of such a permutation might be 987654321, but there are many others, such as 132465879 or 351724698.

Comment: Do you treat the arrangement as a "line" or a "circle"?  That is, do you consider the "last" item as immediately preceding the "first" (wraparound)?

Comment: Good problem!  I note that you've got three posted solutions giving three different results.

Comment: @lulu: Will appreciate your notes on mine (since I'm not too sure about it).

Comment: @barakmanos I will take a look.  First trying it my way (which appears to be a dead end but I'm stubborn).

Comment: @lulu: Thanks. According to Gerry Myerson's answer, it is probably wrong.

Comment: @lulu: Thanks...

Comment: @barakmanos I just posted a solution.  Well, I explained the recursion spotted by someone else.  If you have a second, I'd appreciate it if you would check it.  I've made so many errors in analyzing this that I have little confidence remaining.

Answer (score 3):

For $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, the numbers are tabulated [here](https://oeis.org/A000255), along with lots of information, formulas, references, links, and whatnot. For $n=9$, it says 148329.

Answer (score 3):

Call a permutation of your form "good".

Consider the general problem, with $n$ elements. Let $A_n$ be the number of good permutations (so you are after $A_9$).

The last number, $n$, is special as it can precede anything.  In particular, there are two ways to make a good permutation.

I.  Take a good permutation on $n-1$ letters and place the $n$ in any slot (except the one following ${n-1}$).  This gives $(n-1)A_{n-1}$ good permutations.

II.  Take a permutation on $n-1$ letters that has a single bad pair and insert the $n$ in the middle of the bad pair.  There are $n-2$ bad pairs amongst the $n-1$ letters and there are $A_{n-2}$ ways to arrange the $n-1$ letters so that the arrangement contains the specified bad pair and no other bad pairs.  This gives $(n-2)A_{n-2}$ good permutations on the $n$ letters.

Thus we have the regression $$A_n=(n-1)A_{n-1}+(n-2)A_{n-2}$$ Easy to see that $A_1=1=A_2$ so the first few terms of our regression are $$\{1,1,3,11,53,309,2119,16687,148329\}$$
Of course, this matches the sequence identified by @GerryMyerson in another posted solution.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @barakmanos  thank you.

Comment: In case II, how did you see that there were $A_{n-2}$ ways to arrange the n-1 letters so that there was only the specified bad pair?

Comment: @user84413 Fix a bad pair, say $23$, and treat it as a block.  There are now $n-2$ letters which I can arrange subject to the given restriction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_i$ be the set of permutations with the pattern $i, i+1$ for $1\le i\le 8$ and S the set of all permutations.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion, we have that

$\displaystyle\big|\overline{A_1}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{A_8}\big|=\big|S\big|-\sum_{i}\big|A_i\big|+\sum_{i<j}\big|A_i\cap A_j\big|-\sum_{i<j<k}\big|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k\big|+\cdots$

$\displaystyle=9!-\binom{8}{1}8!+\binom{8}{2}7!-\binom{8}{3}6!+\binom{8}{4}5!-\binom{8}{5}4!+\binom{8}{6}3!-\binom{8}{7}2!+\binom{8}{8}1!$

$=148, 329$

(Notice that this equals $D_8+D_9=14,833+133,496$.)

Answer (score -3):

Let us do it step by step

First take total permutation = 9!(With out any constraint and no repetition)

Ok then as we know 12 in a sequence is not allowed so calculate total number of permutation when there is 12 = 7!

There are total 8 pairs so Ans should be 9!-8*(7!)=322560

Comment: Alas, the events are not independent so this method doesn't apply.  If you look at the same problem for $3$ elements (instead of $9$) your method gives $3!-2^*1!=4$ but the only ways to do it are $\{132\},\{213\},\{321\}$.

Comment: It's wrong. There are $7! \cdot 8$ permutations with $12$.